# Iterating data from an API

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

When I try to iterate data from an API  why am I getting this error `TypeError: books.map is not a function` what is it, and how can I fix it. If someone could help me, I would be grateful, Thanks

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const url="https://json-api-smaiil.herokuapp.com/books"

const Home = () => {

  const [books, setBooks] = useState({})

    const fetchData =async()=>{
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    setBooks(books)
    }

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();
  },[])
  
    return (
        <div>
            {books.map((item)=>{
                const {id, bookName}=item
                return (
                 <div key={id}>
                  <h1>{bookName}</h1>
                </div>   
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: It is because initially you set you state to be an empty object (`{}`). you cannot apply `map()` on object, and hence the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because initially you set you state to be an empty object ({}). you cannot apply map() on object, and hence the error. instead iterate over the object

```
Object.keys(books).map(item => (...do your code here))
```